# json_encode not working on prodution server

Tags: php, json

I have looked through several posts here and none of them worked for me.
I have a json_encode function receiving an array working pretty good on localhost but not in production web server.

Well, php version is 5.6.17 and JSON extension is enabled. 
I tried with this array and worked fine:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This is the array that does´n work: All I get is a blank string and the array is constructed using PDO fetched data and later array_merge and array_merge_recursively function.

```
﻿﻿Array
(
    [id] => 32
    [numero] => 469
    [complemento] => Bloco A
    [observacao] => Qualquer coisa � valida aqui!
    [clientes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 237
                    [id_endereco] => 32
                    [nome] => Joao Paulo
                    [data_inicio] => 22/03/2016
                    [telefones] => Array
                        (
                            [donoTelefone] => 
                        )

                    [comboTelOwner] => <option value='Joao Paulo'>Joao Paulo</option><option value='Augusta Ap Raymo Longo'>Augusta Ap Raymo Longo</option><option value='Karina Longo'>Karina Longo</option>
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [id_endereco] => 32
                    [nome] => Augusta Ap Raymo Longo
                    [data_inicio] => 22/03/2016
                    [telefones] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ddd] => 16
                                    [numero] => 991655725
                                    [id_endereco] => 32
                                    [id_cliente] => 238
                                    [fone_tipo] => 1
                                )

                            [donoTelefone] => Augusta Ap Raymo Longo
                        )

                    [comboTelOwner] => <option value='Joao Paulo'>Joao Paulo</option><option value='Augusta Ap Raymo Longo' selected='selected'>Augusta Ap Raymo Longo</option><option value='Karina Longo'>Karina Longo</option>
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 239
                    [id_endereco] => 32
                    [nome] => Karina Longo
                    [data_inicio] => 22/03/2016
                    [telefones] => Array
                        (
                            [donoTelefone] => 
                        )

                    [comboTelOwner] => <option value='Joao Paulo'>Joao Paulo</option><option value='Augusta Ap Raymo Longo'>Augusta Ap Raymo Longo</option><option value='Karina Longo'>Karina Longo</option>
                )

        )

    [cep] => 14076160
    [estado] => SP
    [cidade] => Ribeir�o Preto
    [bairro] => Independ�ncia
    [tipo_logradouro] => Rua
    [logradouro] =>  Brigadeiro Tobias de Aguiar
    [telefonesComun] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ddd] => 16
                    [numero] => 30110911
                    [id_endereco] => 32
                    [id_cliente] => 
                    [fone_tipo] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ddd] => 16
                    [numero] => 36286574
                    [id_endereco] => 32
                    [id_cliente] => 
                    [fone_tipo] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you share your part of code, where you constructing this array?

Comment: It could be multibyte issue. `json_encode` is probably failed and returning `false`. Try echo [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), what does this print?

Comment: Make sure all your encodings are UTF-8

Comment: Are those UTF-8 characters?

Comment: @LionelChan  json_last_error() gives me Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: After `json_decode()`, output `json_last_error()`.

Comment: PDO has been initialized with UTF8 as you cann see in the connection string: $connString = "mysql:host=" . $servername . ";dbname=sistema_login;charset=utf8";

Comment: @frz3993 json_last_error() gives me Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded but as I said PDO has been initialized with UTF8 as you can see in the connection string: $connString = "mysql:host=" . $servername . ";dbname=sistema_login;charset=utf8"

Comment: You might want to check the db, table and column collation.

Comment: @frz3993 Problem solved! Changing everything to UTF8 was the solution. As you can see I am new in Stackoverflow so I don´t know exactly how to proceed with the awnser. But tks!

Answer (score -2):

For me, your code won't work because you don't use quotes for strings like for id, Bloco A etc... Also you need commas between each element. 
`"id" => 32,"numero" => 469` .

Comment: That's a representation of array, not the JSON.

Comment: I know, here's an example of array in php :  
`$array = array('id' => 12, 'numero' => 20);`